# Automatic hyphenation software

Tags: software-recommendation

Resulting from a discussion over at the Graphic Design StackExchange site about if and how to justify text it is generally concluded that justification is preferred if the text is hyphenated in a proper way (to avoid whitespaces and rivers).

The related questions are

[Justification and hyphenation without proper time and tools?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16351/justification-and-hyphenation-without-proper-time-and-tools)

[Readability and appeal of justified text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16137/readability-and-appeal-of-justified-text%20Readability%20and%20appeal%20of%20justified%20text)

[Does hyphenation increase legibility?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/does-hyphenation-increase-legibility%20Does%20hyphenation%20increase%20legibility?)

An answer to the first link suggests LaTeX but I wonder if there are other programs or tools (for example an extension for LibreOffice) to hyphenate text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyphenation is implemented in LibreOffice Writer 3.5. Go to *Format > Paragraph... > Text Flow* to adjust the settings. There are also settings (perhaps defaults) at *Tools > Options > Language Settings > Writing Aids*, in both the *Available Language Modes* and *Options* panels.

Comment: It's important to remark that you need specific packages for hyhenation. For instance, if you want Italian hyphenation, you will need to install hyphen-it (it's available from the Ubuntu repositories); if you want English (US) hyphenation, install hyphen-en-us.

This and the answer avobe should solve your problem.